# sqlite3 execute update with a return

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am working with ruby on rails and have an sql saying:

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
sql = "UPDATE infos SET value_number = #{val_fun} WHERE pk1 = '#{func[:tbl]}' AND pk2 = '#{clin_row}' AND pk3 = '#{clin_col}' AND  mk1 = '#{patient_id}' AND mk2 = '#{visit_id}'"
connection.execute sql
```

The sql will be executed and if there are corresponding pk1, pk2, pk3, mk1 and mk2, the value of value_number will be updated, if there are no corresponding pk1,pk2... the value will not be updated. In both cases I get a [] as a return.

Is it possible to identify if the value was updated or not without checking before if the corresponding record exist?
 I mean is there a function on connection.execute sql that will tell me how many values were updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't the execute function returns the affected rows count ? No idea about ruby. in .Net it returns the affected row count.

Comment: I get an empty array as a return in ruby